# Receive and display JPG image through UDP

Tags: java, android, image-processing

I am a beginner with Andoroid. I just create an UDP chanel and receive image package(1000bytes). But I have no idea how to display it. What should I do or refer to?

Comment: I can receive the packages but have no idea how to merge them together and display in XOOM.

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to the packet payload as a byte array you can create and Image instance from it.
[Code sample](http://www.programcreek.com/downloads/convert-image-to-byte.txt)

EDIT:
If the image is sent in multiple packets you have to order them correctly. UDP headers has no info for ordering (and there is no guarantee that some won't get lost [more info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533873/why-do-i-get-udp-datagrams-out-of-order-even-with-processes-runnning-locally)) so you have to provide  your own ordering in the payload or switch to TCP.

Comment: I know that and I have added the header, but should I use fileoutputstream to merge the packages or something else? So I can display. The image is in JPEG format.

Comment: Yes I think you should use the java imageIO library which uses image/file streams for creating images from binary data. Just like in the code sample I linked. You can read more about it on Sun's tutorial pages. Maybe there is android specific alternative, but I'm not aware of it.