# UDP packet ordering

Tags: networking, udp

when connecting two network interface adapters directly (using just an ethernet cable, with no networking equipment whatsoever in between), is it correct to assume that all UDP packets sent from one NIC will be received by the other in the same ordering? (I know packet loss will still be a problem, but for this particular question I would like to focus on ordering).

Thanks!

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Theoretically no as UDP implementation in OSI level is at layer 4 i.e. transport layer and the underlying layer of UDP might decide to sequence the packets different way. Remember, the network layer (layer 3) is responsible for fragmentation and reassembly of data.

However, practically, depending on the implementation, it is quite safe to assume that the sequence will remain the same.

Comment: You should never make this assumption.  Lots of things can cause UDP packets to arrive in the receiver's hands out of order, even if they arrive at the NIC in order.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/q/57153969/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/16178457/1048572 or https://stackoverflow.com/q/2533873/1048572: no, it is practically unsafe to assume this

Answer (score 0):

You can't assume anything with UDP: delivery, non-duplication, sequence, ... The only exception is that if you do receive a datagram it is intact.

Comment: As long as you are not using UDP-lite :)

Comment: By `it is intact` you mean *the checksums match*?