# Reliability of small UDP packet on localhost communication

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, linux-kernel, udp

One of the reason that UDP is not a good choice even for localhost communication is due to `out of ordering`, but if I can limit the size of datagram that fragmentation would not occur,

e.g. limit to 1KB of data, so can I assume that the reliability of UDP is the same as TCP?

[1] [Why do I get UDP datagrams out of order even with processes runnning locally?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2533873/why-do-i-get-udp-datagrams-out-of-order-even-with-processes-runnning-locally)

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not the same.
Getting `in-sequence` `packets` is *not the only thing that* comes into picture when you talk about reliability, there's more to it.

**From [RFC 768](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc768.txt) (User Datagram Protocol):**

> This protocol  provides  a procedure  for application  programs  to
>   send messages  to other programs  with a minimum  of protocol
>   mechanism.  **The protocol  is transaction oriented, and delivery and
>   duplicate protection are not guaranteed.**  Applications requiring
>   ordered **reliable** delivery of streams of data should use the
>   Transmission Control Protocol (TCP) [2].

So, by keeping small size for `datagrams`, you may ensure that the out-of-order delivery never happens but still you can't ensure the data is correctly received at the other end. This still holds good even if you are sending data on a local host. A `bit-error` can occur for any unknown reason, that's why you have `check-sum` in the `header`. If the `check-sum` at the receiving end doesn't match then the `packet` is discarded without the sender knowing about it. This doesn't happen in `TCP` since the receiver sends an `ACK` to the sender on receiving the correct data.